# NativeProcess API Java Debugging?

Tags: java, apache-flex, air

What is your way to debug Java side when nativeProcess.standardInput.write method is invoked by Flex side? I know that it is possible but don't know how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to attach your Eclipse debugger to a running Java process you need to start that process with the following Java options…

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8001,server=y,suspend=n
```

Once you have done this and have restarted the server, you can use your Eclipse to attach to the running process. From Eclipse go to the Debug manager and create a new Remote Java Application configuration for the process you want to connect to. Set the port number to 8001, the same as that of the options. You will also need to enter the hostname for the machine running the Java process. That is pretty much it…